# Automated publishing using Teamcity

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, teamcity

I'm a newbie to configuration management and I'm required to implement a solution wherein I need to publish a new version of my Windows application on shared Network drive using Teamcity's Trigger.
We already have a continuous integration Teamcity server which is used for continuos build integration. Is it possible to publish a new version everytime along with the build using MSBUILD or something?

Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. I believe you already have a `Build/Compile` MSBuild target.
So now you can create `Deploy.targets` which simply executes a `<Copy>` MSBuild Task. 
`InputFiles` attribute specifies files which are produced by `Build/Compile` target and `OutputFiles` would be the destination network folder path.
After that you have to make Deploy target to be dependent on Build target by specifying `DependsOn="Build"`

Comment: Thanks sleev, I really do appreciate your response. Would it be possible for you to help me with some tags? It would be  life saver. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your suggestion, Im looking at Clickonce deployment. Is there an article that you know of?

Comment: @Ankur Agarwal: Unfortunately I'm not familar with ClickOnce deployment and can help only with MSBuild+TeamCity